# Moving an asp.net web forms site on azure without coding it again to use azure blob storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms

I have a asp.net web forms web site that uses many files from server disk, accept uploads, processing files on the server. All the files stored in the web server's disks.

I would like to move my site to azure web sites. But to do that i think we need to update site code to keep files in azure blobs and process from it. Right now we are not able to that. So can i move my web site to azure without using azure blobs? Is there any way i can move all my site and files to azure, keep and publish on azure but not on azure blobs?

Using Virtual Machine is not an option to us right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Azure App Service/Website comes with persisted storage, which is technically an Azure storage blob mapped to the local file system. However, your code need not be aware of that. The details are described to the *File System* section [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment).

If you can configure paths for your server files, this persisted storage should suffice.

Comment: Hi. Yes we can play with the paths in the app. If we deploy our app to azure as it is we only need to change the paths? is that all? How we can browse or access this files to manage? How it will be accessed by http? I can definitely research on this but since i heard it only from you i am just asking it to you. What does this storage called? Where to look for technical details? Lastly, Premium apps are too expensive and standard is not enough. Can we expand the size by paying extra?

Comment: https://<webappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ can be used to access a file browser and you would be able to browse to it manually to upload/download or edit files (apart from using deployment scripts to place files in the storage). Go to the Kudu home page -> Debug menu -> CMD option to browse around. I am not aware of any way of paying for extra space.